# Cálculo efectivo entre fechas en excel

Tags: excel

Vuelvo a recurrir a vosotros, y es que llevo unos días dándole vueltas al cálculo entre dos fechas para saber la antiguedad en la empresa, y no sou capaz

primero intenté ésta fórmula buscada por internet

```
=DATEDIF(B5;C5;"Y")  & DATEDIF(B5;C5;"YM") & DATEDIF(B5;C5;"MD")
```

Pero me da error: #¿NOMBRE?

Luego he probado con ésta, y si que me da resultados, pero no los entiendo

```
=(AÑO(C5)-AÑO(B5))*12+MES(C5)-MES(B5)
```

Pero entre el 01/01/1981 a la fecha de hoy, me da 485

Alguien me puede ayudar ? gracias

Comment: La antiguedad que quieres realizar en en años, días? Sería bueno que pongas los datos que tienes en cada celda

Comment: Si perdón, lo puse abajo pero no lo especifiqué. En la celda B5 tengo 01/01/1981, en la celda C5 tengo la de hoy con la función que mencionó @Trasgu en su respuesta HOY()

Comment: Parece que tu pregunta ya fue respondida, con respecto a la fórmula que mencionas que no entiendes **(AÑO(C5)-AÑO(B5))*12+MES(C5)-MES(B5)** solamente esta hallando la diferencia de meses entre 2 fechas por eso primero halla la diferencia de años entre las 2 fechas y lo multiplica por 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suele ser un cálculo bastante frecuente, de echo, yo lo tengo realizado en varias ocasiones, te paso el código

La función DATEDIF es la misma que SIFECHA, que es la que yo te paso en el ejemplo

En lugar de tomar dos fechas, la indicada para el cálculo y la actual que se la das en otra celda, yo te puse la función de excel HOY(), así que cualquier día que abras el archivo te realizará el cálculo exacto y no tendrás que modificar la fecha, aunque podrías perfectamente poner esa función vinculada a la misma celda y que sea la celda la que vaya actualizando la fecha actual

En mi fórmula, ya te digo que la tengo utilizada muchas veces, pongo un primer condicional de si la diferencia entre las fechas es menor al año, el resultado te arrojaría 0 años, para evitarlo, pongo que en caso de ser menor al año ponga "", o más bien, no ponga nada

La "Y" calcula la diferencia de los años

Las "YM" calcula la diferencia de los meses, ignorando los años

Las "MD" calcula la diferencia de los días ignorando los meses y los años

```
="Llevas " & SI(SIFECHA(B5;C5;"Y")=0;"";SIFECHA(B5;C5;"Y"))  & " años, " & SIFECHA(B5;C5;"YM") & " meses y " & SIFECHA(B5;C5;"MD") & " días en la empresa"
```

en ésta otra fórmula que comentas no saber el resultado que te arroja, la verdad que no lo he calculado

```
=(AÑO(C5)-AÑO(B5))*12+MES(C5)-MES(B5)
```

Pero viendo la fórmula, supongo que será el resultado de restar la fecha indicada de la fecha actual en años, por el resultado de la diferencia entre las fechas en meses

EDITADA

Actualiada la fórmula sustituyendo la función HOY() por la celda C5

La función tiene una seríe de parámetros para calcular la diferencia entre fechas:

"Y" - calcula el total de años entre dos fechas (En el caso que nos ocupa, no variaría, pues es lo que usamos)

"M" - calcula el total de meses entre dos fechas (En nuestro ejemplo daría 485 meses, o sea, 40 años (El resultado de la "Y" + el resultado de "YM", 5 meses) y 5 meses)

"D" - calcula el total de días entre dos fechas. En el ejemplo serían 14.783 días (40 x 365 = 14.600 + 5 meses x total de días + días)

Cuando a en la función se colocan "YM" ó "MD", lo que hace es ignorar el cálculo de lo que arrojaría el primer carácter, en el primer caso ignora los años, y en el segundo, ignora tanto los años como los meses, y arroja solo el resultado del resto que le queda tras ignorar ese cálculo

No se si me he explicado bien

Comment: Muchas gracias @el.trasgu, pero podrías explicarme lo de ignorar los meses y los años ? gracias

Comment: Te contesto en la respuesta

Comment: Sí @el.trasgu, creo que ahora mas o menos lo he entendido, haré varias prácticas sobre ello para asentar vuestras explicaciones. muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Una aclaración más respecto a tu pregunta, pensaba ponerlo como comentario; mejor lo escribo como respuesta.
la Función `DATEIF` funciona cuando la versión del office que usas está en inglés; en caso la versión de tu office está en español se debe usar la función `SIFECHA` el cual no voy explicar porque ya fue respondida en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/464150/193364

Comment: gracias por la aclaración @Joshin, ahora entiendo de porque se cita tanto en google cuando buscas comparación de fechas en excel, y a mi no me funcionaba